# Twig/Symfony how to format currency

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to format currency in twig and im trying to use the `format_currency_number` filter, which yields `20,00 XXX`
Instead of the `XXX` i would like to get the currency symbol `€`

Here is my current code:

```
<td class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3 text-end">{{ amount|format_currency_number }}</td>
```

I know about the `format_currency` filter, but it expects a string as input instead of a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you **could** then just pass the number as a string by concatinating it into a string

```
{{ ("" ~ amount)|format_currency('EUR') }}
```

I didn´t try but i guess it should work

UPDATE: for me format_currency works also fine when used on a number not a string

e.g

```
{% set amount = 20 %}
{{ amount|format_currency('EUR') }}
```

displays 20,00€

Comment: Wow it does indeed work with numbers. I coul'd swear i tried that and it didn't work.